# Crash - Share App Extension - Image - iOS 13 - EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY (limit=120 MB, unused=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, image, memory

I'm having a "fight" with the crash that appeared 10 days ago and it's still appearing when I want to share a picture with my app. Notice that this feature has been working without a problem for the past 12 months.

In Share App Extension crash **EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY (limit=120 MB, unused=0x0)** **happens** at UIImage.draw(in: rect) UIImage extension method when a selected image for sharing starts to draw itself to CGRect preview view.

```
extension UIImage {
func resizeImageOriginalSize(_ targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    var actualHeight: Float = Float(self.size.height)
    var actualWidth: Float = Float(self.size.width)
    let maxHeight: Float = Float(targetSize.height)
    let maxWidth: Float = Float(targetSize.width)
    var imgRatio: Float = actualWidth / actualHeight
    let maxRatio: Float = maxWidth / maxHeight
    var compressionQuality: Float = 0.5
    //50 percent compression
    
    if actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth {
        if imgRatio < maxRatio {
            //adjust width according to maxHeight
            imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight
            actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth
            actualHeight = maxHeight
        }
        else if imgRatio > maxRatio {
            //adjust height according to maxWidth
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth
            actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight
            actualWidth = maxWidth
        }
        else {
            actualHeight = maxHeight
            actualWidth = maxWidth
            //compressionQuality = 0.5
        }
    }
    
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: CGFloat(actualWidth), height: CGFloat(actualHeight))
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, CGFloat(compressionQuality))
    self.draw(in: rect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage!
}}
```

The memory usage limit for Share Extension is 120mb, everything above it OS crashes the app. I was checking Memory Usage and the normal value is around 70MB before drawing the image in the rectangle, then the memory usage jumps immediately over 120MB ( around 130MB ).

The crash is mostly happening on the line:

```
self.draw(in: rect)
```

I can't figure out why sudden memory increase is happening.

What's happening here and how to fix it?

Comment: It is not leaking, before drawing the image is decompressed, so memory consumption grows. You have to use smaller images (by dimension, by file size, etc.)

Comment: This happens to me when I try to resize large images. So the solution "You have to use smaller images" is not really helpful. The question is, how to resize big images that this error does not occur?

Comment: This is happening to me ... did any of you guys solve it?

Comment: Did you use dataWithContentsOfURL with option NSDataReadingUncached? Try replace with option NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe

Answer (score 0):

If you are using:

> `Data(contentsOf: url)`

Try to replace it with option **NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe**:

> `Data(contentsOf: url, options: .mappedIfSafe)`

Working with large files (mostly videos) will no longer provide this type of error.

*Before:*
[image: Before]

*After:*
[image: After]

Comment: I like this answer just some things to consider: Safety: The ```"ifSafe"``` in ```.mappedIfSafe``` implies that memory mapping will only be used if it's safe to do so. If it's not, then the method will go back to loading the data into memory, which might lead to the same memory issues if the file is large.

File Changes: If the underlying file changes while you're accessing a memory-mapped version, you can run into unexpected behavior or crashes. This is a general caveat with memory-mapped files.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guide you on resizing of Images inside the share extension, whenever you try to resize the images try to use sequential queues and perform single task at a time, this will not take much memory and the memory will not exceed.

For sequential executing tasks.

```
private let imageResizeQueue = OperationQueue()
private let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
```

in viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageResizeQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1 // Process operations sequentially
    self.resizeBeforeDisplay()
}
```

in resieBeforeDisplay function use

```
   let resizeOperation = ImageResizeOperation(image: img)
   resizeOperation.completionBlock = {[weak self, weak resizeOperation] in}
   self.imageResizeQueue.addOperation(resizeOperation) }
```

and final code is to notify when all the operations are executed.

```
dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) { [weak self] in }
```

This will allow you to perform one task at a time and will not take memory and share extension will work smoothly.